# Gitlab-CI: How do I run a job on a specific server?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set up Gitlab and Gitlab-CI on a k8s cluster in AWS. I have jobs that use a lot of resources. I want to run these jobs on specific instances in AWS. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Kubernetes configuration

You need to add a node selector which enable you to assign pods on specific nodes

```
kubectl label nodes <node-name> gitlab=true
```

## Gitlab Runner configuration

- Specify a [tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags) associated to the runner. In your case, uncheck the Run untagged jobs option.
- Specify a node selector using the keyword `node_selector` :

```
  [runners.kubernetes.node_selector]
    gitlab = "true"
```

Check a more complete example of `config.toml` on gitlab [website](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#define-keywords-in-the-config-toml).

## Gitlab CI configuration

[Refer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags) the tag of your runner in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
job:
  tags:
    - big_server
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. That will cause all jobs to run on that node. I want only one specific job to run on that node while all other jobs run on any other node. the specific node will have a lot of resources that are needed for the specific job, while all other jobs can run on any other node.

Comment: I edited my answer adding the Gitlab runner tag and the correspondence in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Comment: Thank you. I'll need a second runner. That'll solve it.